# Github actions: Run step / job in a workflow if changes happen in specific folder

Tags: github-actions

Is there any way for us to control what jobs/steps to run in a workflow based on the changes in a specific folder

Eg:

I have said, following folders in my git repo : a, b, c
On every PR merge to my branch I will trigger a workflow. The workflow will execute jobs say,
A -> B -> C. I want to run job A only if changes are present for folder `"a/**"`, B for `"b/**"` and so on.

So, If in the PR changes only happen in `"a/**"`and `"b/**"` workflow will skip job execution for `C`, making the workflow run to be `A`->`B`

Comment: This might also help https://www.meziantou.net/executing-github-actions-jobs-or-steps-only-when-specific-files-change.htm

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could use the [paths-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) custom action with `if` conditions **at the jobs or step levels**, using a `setup` job as preliminary to check if your specific path has been updated, saving the result as an output.

#### Here is an example

```
name: Paths Filter Example

on: [push, workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  paths-filter:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.workflows }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
      id: filter
      with:
        filters: |
          workflows:
            - '.github/workflows/**'
    # run only if 'workflows' files were changed
    - name: workflow tests
      if: steps.filter.outputs.workflows == 'true'
      run: echo "Workflow file"

    # run only if not 'workflows' files were changed
    - name: not workflow tests
      if: steps.filter.outputs.workflows != 'true'
      run: echo "NOT workflow file"

  next-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Wait from the paths-filter to be completed before starting next-job
    needs: paths-filter
    if: needs.paths-filter.outputs.output1 == 'true'
    steps:
      ...
```

That way, you could have something like this in your jobs: `A` --> `B` or `A` --> `C` depending on the path that has been updated.

Comment: One small adjustment in the syntax for `next-job`: It should read either 
`if: needs.paths-filter.outputs.output1 == 'true'` or `if: ${{ needs.paths-filter.outputs.output1 == 'true' }}`

Answer (score 20):

Yes: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#registry_package

This is the syntax:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'a/**'
      - 'b/**'
```

Comment: This controls in workflow level. It doesnt control what jobs to execute in the workflow depending on the path. What I want would may be a `if:` tag in job / step to check if a path has change

Comment: You will have to make one workflow per job - the condition applies only to the workflow as a whole

Comment: Please read the question carefully before posting this unrelated answer.