# Triggering folder-specific GH action builds for a monorepo with many lambdas inside of it

Tags: github-actions, monorepo

I understand that I can trigger GitHub actions when changes are made to a [specific path](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#using-filters-to-target-specific-paths-for-pull-request-or-push-events), however I'm looking for a way to not only trigger under this condition, but to also customize the build depending on which path activates the build.

The reason why is I have been asked to build a monorepo that will consist of many top-level folders. Each folder needs to be built into a different AWS Lambda, but only when files underneath it have been merged into the `dev` branch. So for instance if this is my repo:

```
my-monorepo/
    common/
    auth-lambda/
    payment-lambda/
    notifications-lambda/
    messaging-lambda/
    directory-lambda/
    billing-lambda/
        billing-file-1.js
        billing-file-2.js
    warehouse-lambda/
    ... (dozens more)
```

Then I want to set up 1+ GH Actions such that:

The code living under `billing-lambda` gets built when source files underneath it (either `billing-file-1.js` or `billing-file-2.js`) get merged from feature branches into the `dev` branch; but *only* the `billing-lambda` code gets built and deployed by the action.

And similar for all the other folders/lambdas.

Any ideas as to how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Did you think about a possible solution? Maybe, by filtering files on the `push` event.

Comment: You could trigger your workflow using a PATH, but then check on a setup job if a specific path has been updated to trigger later jobs / steps. The [path-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) job is useful for this kind of behavior. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708306/github-actions-run-step-job-in-a-workflow-if-changes-happen-in-specific-folde/70711156#70711156) gives an example.