# How can I configure GitHub Actions to only run for modified service?

Tags: docker, github-actions, devops, amazon-ecr

I have a monolithic application that hosts different microservices in separate folders. Here is an example directory structure:

/project/service1

/project/service2

I have created separate AWS ECR repositories for each service, and I have written GitHub Actions code that builds the Docker image of each service and pushes it to the respective ECR repository whenever a release is created on GitHub. These are separate GitHub Actions codes for each service. I append the version of the release obtained from GitHub as the version of the image in ECR.

I have two questions: I don't want to build and push images for all services every time I create a release. Instead, I want it to build and push only the service (folder) that has been modified. How can I achieve this? What approach should I follow? My other question is that I can no longer use the version number entered in the release because images will no longer be built for each service. Each service will have different versions. How should I manage this versioning?

Project Language: NodeJS

Here is an example GitHub Actions YAML for one of my services:

```
name: Deploy core to Amazon ECS

on:
  release:
    types: ["published"]

env:
  AWS_REGION: eu-central-1
  ECR_REPOSITORY: lake-core
  CONTAINER_NAME: core

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
      
      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        id: build-image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.ref_name }}
          WORKSPACE: ${{ github.workspace }} 
        run: |
          cd core
          cp -r ../shared/ ./shared
          sed 's/\.\.\/shared/\.\/shared/g' package.json > package-tmp.json 
          docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest .
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY --all-tags
          rm -r ./shared
          rm package-tmp.json
          echo "image=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github actions: Run step / job in a workflow if changes happen in specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708306/github-actions-run-step-job-in-a-workflow-if-changes-happen-in-specific-folde)

Comment: An option could also be the use more than one workflow, one to check the folder path before triggering the second one (maybe using a reusable workflow).

Comment: Hi @GuiFalourd thanks. Yes, I checked the link you sent and I'm having the same problem with it. But I have a problem. If the action code is triggered as on: push, I don't get an error. But when I trigger it with on:release it doesn't watch for file changes. The files are working as if they have never changed.

Comment: It might be because a release event in the github context doesn't have a list of updated files. Would it be an option to trigger on a push or a tag creation instead? This should resolve your issue, as you could create the release through an action as well, and perform the rest of your operation in a sequencial job.

Comment: Hello, in order not to waste any more time here, as you also suggested, I reverted back to the 'on:push' event. I absorbed the issue in this way.