# How to skip building DotNet and only deploy to azure? Github Actions to Azure Web Service

Tags: .net, github-actions, continuous-deployment

## My Struggle

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project hosted on GitHub, deploying to Azure Web Services. The project structure includes both an REST API application and static files in the wwwroot folder (JavaScript, JSON). I want to optimize our GitHub Actions workflow to bypass the entire build process when only files in the wwwroot folder are modified.

## Current Workflow

Our current GitHub workflow triggers a build and deploy process upon merging into the main branch. The sample workflow is configured as follows:

```
name: Build and Conditional Deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - MyOwnApp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    if: contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[build]')
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'MyOwnApp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE }}
          package: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy-wwwroot:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[build]')"
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: List directory structure
        run: dir  # For Windows runner

      - name: Deploy wwwroot to Azure Web App
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'MyOwnApp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE }}
          package: MyOwnApp/wwwroot
```

## Desired Behavior:

I want the workflow to Perform a full build and deploy when changes are made outside of wwwroot and to only update wwwroot on Azure when changes are confined to that directory.

## Issue Encountered:

When I commit changes solely in wwwroot/js/sample.js with a commit message like 'sample edited', the file updates on Azure and I can access the updated .js via browser, but the actual dotnet application breaks. For some reason even accessing a neighboring file in wwwroot (wwwroot/js/sample.json) results in a 'The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.' error. However, if I build by including '[build]' in the commit message (e.g., 'sample edited again [build]'), everything functions correctly after a lengthy build process.

## Question:

How can I modify the GitHub Actions workflow to bypass the build process for changes exclusively in wwwroot, without breaking the application?

Comment: You could use a [path-builder](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) action in a setup job to check if the directory have been updated or not, and then execute the other jobs using an if expression according to the condition you wished. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708306/github-actions-run-step-job-in-a-workflow-if-changes-happen-in-specific-folde/70711156#70711156) could give some insights.

Comment: Well, as it is now, I don't have an issue using [build] in the commit message. The bigger issue is that I don't know why my app is breaking when I'm skipping the build step. Once I figure that out, I will definitely apply path-builders to streamline my process. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
branches:
    - main
paths:
    include:
      - YourProjPath/*

    # for exampple:
    #   - scripts/*

    # You can also exclude specific files in your case
    exclude:
      - wwwroot/*
```